# Stored procedure and select query return different result in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using MySQL and MySQL workbench.

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `sms_stats`(
                IN  fromDate VARCHAR(8), 
                IN  toDate VARCHAR(8), 
                IN  smsCost VARCHAR(8), 
                OUT bank_id int, 
                OUT bank_name VARCHAR(100), 
                OUT totalSms VARCHAR(20),
                OUT totalCost VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN
SELECT c.bank_id as bank_id,
       b.name as bank_name,
       count(c.bank_id) as totalSms, 
       (count(c.bank_id) * smsCost) as totalCost 
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN banks b on c.bank_id = b.id
WHERE sms_sent = 1 
AND sms_sent_datetime >= fromDate 
AND sms_sent_datetime <= toDate
GROUP BY bank_id, bank_name;
END
```

Why stored procedure return (I executed with: call prenotabanca.sms_stats('20220101', '20220420', '0.08', @bank_id, @bank_name, @totalSms, @totalCost);) a different result from

```
SELECT c.bank_id as bank_id,
       b.name as bank_name,
       count(c.bank_id) as totalSms, 
       (count(c.bank_id) * '0.08') as totalCost 
FROM prenotabanca.calendar c
LEFT JOIN prenotabanca.banks b on c.bank_id = b.id
WHERE sms_sent = 1 
AND sms_sent_datetime >= '20220101'
AND sms_sent_datetime <= '20220420'
GROUP BY bank_id, bank_name;
```

Comment: Please add sample data as text.

Comment: What is the difference type? What is different - rows amount? some (what) values? PS. What is the reason to define unused OUT parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, the problem was in the group by, I didn't use the alias and the column bank id  is contained in several tables.